C23 by Microsoft C compiler support: bugs or unimplemented features?
I tried to test the C23 code from ACCU23 presentation, but it doesn't work. Here's what I get in Visual Studio under std:clatest switch:

The struct return type doesn't generate an error on line 1, but does generate on line 15.
auto doesn't work (line 13). IntelliSense shows <error-type> instead of inferred type (screenshot in the end of line).
constexpr doesn't work (line 5).
true doesn't work (line 24), however bool does work (line 21).
nullptr doesn't work (line 18).

Is it OK it doesn't work? Or do I do something wrong? Maybe there are some other switches I need to power on?


MSVC doesn't support C23. It doesn't even support all of C99. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/compiler_support

@interjay Then why std:clatest switch after C17 switch?

They may have added a few of the C23 features. But the fact that there's no C23 switch should tell you that they don't claim to support it.

Please post code as text, not as pictures of text. If you wish to point out line numbers then post both the picture and the text.

The presentation is using gcc in conforming C23 mode.
C23 was finished as far as voting on technical stuff in summer 2022, meaning that non-profit compilers like gcc and clang had almost 2 and a half year until the formal ISO release in October 2024 to fix support for the most important features. They mostly managed, some features are still not supported.
So what did Microsoft do during those 2 and a half years? Well, the latest and greatest MSVC last got updated in year 2022 to finally support ISO 9899:1989/Amd1:1995.
Note that you have to compile with /Zc:__STDC__ or otherwise you still get non-conforming ISO C:1989 minus technical amendments.
There's other /Zc options you can play with in case you want to get closer to something similar to older versions of the C language, like for example /Zc:preprocessor meaning "yes pretty please I want a working preprocessor" Which, much like a keyboard and computer screen, is quite a handy tool to have when coding in C.
Or /Zc:auto to get C++ auto, not quite the same thing as C23 auto. (Why you'd ever want to use either in C code beats me.)
You can also get it to compile according to potentially non-conforming subsets of other withdrawn ISO standards such as C11 or C17 by adding /std:c11 or /std:c17.
/std:clatest and /std:c17 is as of today's date the same thing.
Try out:
printf("%ld", __STDC_VERSION__);

With MSVC 19.40 (VS 17.10) /Zc:__STDC__ /std:clatest I get 201710.
bool does not work without including stdbool.h, which is correct behavior, so if you somehow got it working you might be compiling the code the wrong way.

error C2065: 'bool': undeclared identifier


"Why you'd ever want to use either in C code beats me" -- because any repetition leads to copy&pasted code that breeds divergent code paths that don't get maintained equally. Generally speaking, code that doesn't use type inference in languages that support it is where I always start debugging when I encounter problems -- those people don't understand basic principles, so they certainly won't understand smart pointers, memory safety or spans, and their code is rife with memory corruption.

@Blindy Why is the new auto keyword from C++11 or C23 dangerous?
